# Simple Divison for Calculator not working

Tags: java, swing, division, joptionpane

I'm Trying to make a calculator that will figure in tax, tip, and splitting between multiple people, but the last feature isn't working and I can't figure out why. I know it will probably be a simple fix but I'm new to Java so I just can't find it. Note: this is my first actual Java program so please be understanding with my probably obvious mistake.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class TaxFinder { 

     static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static double priceD, taxD, totalTax, total, priceTipped, pricePP;
    public static int peopleI;
    public static String price, tax, people, ifTip, tip, ifSplit;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        ifTip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Was your purchase in a restaurant?");

         if (ifTip.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){ 
             price = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What was the cost of your bill ($)?");
             priceD = Double.parseDouble(price);

             tax = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your tax rate (decimal)?"); 
             taxD = Double.parseDouble(tax);

             tip = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Do you want to tip 5, 10, 15, or 20% ?"); 

             if (tip.equals("5")){ 
                 priceTipped = priceD * .05;
             }

             else if (tip.equals("10")){ 
                 priceTipped = priceD * .1;
                 //System.out.println("Your price tipped is " + priceTipped);
             }

             else if (tip.equals("15")){ 
                 priceTipped = priceD * .15;
             }

             else if (tip.equals("20")){ 
                 priceTipped = priceD * .2;
             }

             totalTax = priceD * taxD;
             total = priceD + totalTax + priceTipped;

         } 

         else if (ifTip.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){ 
             price = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How much did your purchase cost ($)?");
             priceD = Double.parseDouble(price);
             tax = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is your tax rate (decimal)?");
             taxD = Double.parseDouble(tax);

         totalTax = priceD * taxD;
        total = priceD + totalTax;
         }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total is: $" + total, "Shopping Calculator", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

        ifSplit = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Are you splitting the cost with other people?");

        if (ifSplit.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")){ 
            people = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many people including you?");
            peopleI = Integer.parseInt(people);

            pricePP = total / peopleI; 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total is $" + total + " per person", "Shopping Calculator", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Have a nice day!", "Shopping Calculator", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        } 

        else if (ifSplit.equalsIgnoreCase("no")){ 
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Have a nice day!", "Shopping Calculator", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try casting peopleI to double when you calculate the pricePP

Comment: @MadProgrammer `total` is a `double`

Comment: @ZouZou I don't want to cast the result, just one side of the division...

Comment: @MadProgrammer What's the point of casting `peopleI` in `pricePP = total / peopleI;` ? It's already `double/int`, so it won't perfom integer division. Or maybe I did'nt get what you want to meant.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `pricePP` instead of `total` variable here :

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The total is $" + total
                + " per person", "Shopping Calculator",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

because you output another variable, which isn't devided.

Comment: I see. Like I said, I'm a very new programmer so I was expecting to have the mistake be obvious. Thank you for your time though, it helped a lot